# The image url created in my Google cloud function code returns a 401 when put in an <img /> tag on my site?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

When an image is uploaded to Firebase storage, I am using a cloud function to resize it. I then take the URL to that image and insert it into the Firestore DB. When the DB record is updated, the front end app sees that change and creates an  tag with the URL set as the 'src'. The network call returns a 401.

As far as I can tell, I either need to whitelist domains somewhere in a Google admin panel or I am getting the wrong URL to begin with.

When I look at the file in the Firebase console, I get a URL with a  different domain then the one received in the cloud function. Since the storage domain is different, it would make sense that I need to setup a whitelist. If so, where is it?

- console: `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...?alt=media`
- function: `https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/...`

I *could* do a string replace, and if I go into the DB and manually change the domain, first part of the path, and add the `alt=media` param, the image will load. I'm hoping someone has a less hacky answer than that.

I setup the bucket to allow reading.

```js
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
    }
  }
}
```

My cloud function follows this: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/image-thumbnail-resizer-cloud-function/. Here are the important parts:

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
admin.initializeApp();

export const imageResize = functions.storage
.object()
.onFinalize(async object => {
  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(object.bucket)
  bucket.upload(imagePath, {
      destination: join(bucketDir, imageName)
    }).then(async (data) => {
      const file = data[0]
      const [imageLink] = await file.getSignedUrl({
        action: 'read',
        expires: '04-03-2100'
      })
      // also tried this
      // const [fileMeta] = await file.getMetadata()
      // const imageLink = fileMeta.selfLink
```

And then I write it to the proper Firestore DB record. The write works fine, the URL doesn't work.

---

*Expected* The URL I get from file.getSignedUrl() should load in an image tag

*Actual* The URL returns a 401 when loaded in an image tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this solution that uses a different pattern from the standard examples that are triggered by uploading the image to storage.

You can take a look to this link.

[Firebase Cloud Function to resize image on firestore create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49575174/firebase-cloud-function-to-resize-image-on-firestore-create?rq=1)